# Custom FlowLayoutPanel: Get inside elements posotion and/or Rectangle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, usercontrol

He creado un control de usuario customizado a partir del control FlowLayoutPanel que contiene Paneles customizados dentro, añadidos dinámicamente. Quiero obtener la posición de los controles dentro de este FlowLayoutPanel para completar el metodo isPointOverPanel.¿Alguna idea? Gracias por adelantado

```
{
public partial class FlowDynamicPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    private PictureBox addIcon;
    List<ResizablePanel> resizablePanels;

    public FlowDynamicPanel()
    {
        resizablePanels = new List<ResizablePanel>();
        ResizablePanel rp = CreateNewPanel();
        Controls.Add(rp);
        addIcon = new PictureBox
        {
            Image = Resource1.adIcon,
            Size = new Size(100, 100),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        };
        addIcon.MouseClick += AddIcon_MouseClick;
        this.Controls.Add(addIcon);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Controls.Add(CreateNewPanel());
        Controls.SetChildIndex(addIcon, Controls.Count);
    }

    private ResizablePanel CreateNewPanel()
    {

        ResizablePanel _newRp = new ResizablePanel
        {
            Size = new Size(40, 40),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        };
        resizablePanels.Add(_newRp);
        return _newRp;
    }


   public ResizablePanel IsPointOverPanel(Point p)
    {
      //Obtener la posición de los paneles dentro de this y comprobar si p esta dentro.
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Iván, una idea que se me ocurre es *(si ya agregas los páneles dinámicamente)* puedes asignarles el evento "MouseHover" y "MouseLeave" para que puedas intentar obtener las posiciones de los controles. Este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvSvEXxVCFA) es una muestra de cómo puede usarlo o busca `c# panel winform mouseover` en Google.

Comment: No quiero saber si el raton esta encima.Quiero saber si un punto pertenece al control

Comment: intenta usando `this.ClientRectangle.Contains()`